# Equivalence between two definitions of Lattice (order theory)

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I have come across two different definitions of a lattice. The first one is that a lattice is a partially ordered set with every pair of elements having an infimum and a supremum. The other definition is that a lattice is a set with two binary operations meet and join defined on it such that L is closed under these two operations and these operations satisfy the laws of commutation, association and absorption.

Now, I want to see if both these definitions are equivalent to each other. Can anyone help?

Comment: They are equivalent. Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Connection_between_the_two_definitions

Comment: I can understand the proof from the 'order theoretic notion' to the notion using the binary operations, as given in the Wikipedia page provided. However, I cannot understand the proof of the opposite direction.

Comment: That is because the proof there is incomplete. However, I presume you know the necessary axioms and can fill them in. For example, if $a\le b\iff a=a\land b$, then [R]: $a\le a$ follows from $a=a\land a$ (which is a theorem for binary operation lattices); [AS]: $a\le b$ and $b\le a$ mean $a=a\land b$ and $b=b\land a$, thus $a=b$; finally [T]: $a\le b, b\le c$ mean $a=a\land b$ and $b=b\land c$ so $a=a\land (b\land c)=(a\land b)\land c=a\land c$ so $a\le c$ ... The next thing to prove is that each two elements $a,b$ have $\sup(a,b)=a\lor b$ and $\inf(a,b)=a\land b$ - should be doable, I hope...

Comment: ([R], [AS], [T] stand for reflexivity, antisymmetry, transitivity. Anyway, give it a try and post here if you cannot get it going, this is really mostly an exercise. You will use absorption at some point.)

Comment: 1. Is the partial order implied by the commutative, associative and absorption law axioms?

Comment: 2. Does the sup(a,b) and inf(a,b) existing for all pair of elements follow from the fact that L is closed under the meet and join operations?

Comment: 1. I just demonstrated those to you above. 2. Yes, but you would need to prove that, and in fact you will prove a bit more specific thing - that $\sup$ is $\lor$ and $\inf$ is $\land$.

Comment: Do all lattices satisfy: a$\land$b = a or a$\land$b = b ?

Comment: Of course not. However, we use those sentences to define an *ordered* lattice when we have an *algebraic* lattice. Refer again to the Wikipedia article. You *define* that $a\le b$ *if and only if* $a\land b=a$. Then, for the relation $\le$ *defined in such manner* you *prove* that (a) The relation $\le$ is a partial ordering (shown to you above!) and (b) With respect to this partial ordering, the meet of any two elements $x\land y$ is their *infimum* (in terms of the newly-introduced relation $\le$) and you also prove that the join $x\lor y$ is the *supremum* of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: How are we to define an order on a lattice (algebraic lattice) for which it isn't the case that a$\land$b=a or a$\land$b=b? If it is not possible to do so, can we say that a lattice is a poset (with every pair of elements having an infimum and supremum)? It seems to me that then some lattices would not be posets with every pair having an infimum and supremum. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't quite understand what is worrying you. If for two elements $a,b$ it is valid that $a=a\land b$, then we say $a\le b$. If it is valid that $b=a\land b$ then we say that $b\le a$. If *neither* is valid, then neither $a\le b$ nor $b\le a$. In other words, you get something that is certainly a *partial* order but not necessarily a *total* order.

Comment: Take an example of $\mathbb N$ with the relation $\mid$ ("divides"). This is an ordered lattice because for any two elements you have $\sup(x,y)=\operatorname{lcm}(x, y)$ and $\inf(x,y)=\gcd(x,y)$. Call those two "join" and "meet". It can help you to "reconstruct" the "divides" relation by saying $a\mid b\iff a=\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: I have finally understood it now. Thank you very much for your patient and kindhearted responses.

Comment: Not a problem. This was more of a chat than a coherent answer, so this question may be left formally unanswered (unless someone is willing to spent a lot of time typing the proofs to the minute details - I certainly won't!). Glad that it was helpful, though!